# How to split a Roth IRA into multiple accounts?

Tags: united-states, ira, retirement, roth-ira

I currently have a roth IRA with a large brokerage firm but to increase the diversification of my portfolio, I'd like to invest in some securities that this brokerage firm will not invest in (in my case Peer to Peer lending notes, but I can imagine other examples, but as Dilip Sarwate points out there are limitations here). The answer to this [question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/932/can-you-have-a-roth-ira-and-a-traditional-ira-what-about-two-separate-ira-accou) says it is possible to split a roth IRA, which I interpret to mean that I could for example have part of my roth IRA with lending club and another part in a Schwab brokerage account and another part in a traditional bank account. How do I go about doing this legally, without incurring any tax penalties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a trustee to trustee exchange. You will need to contact both companies to coordinate the paperwork. As long as both accounts are the same type (traditional\Roth) you are fine.

You can also do a rollover where you have the check but there are some limitations and deadlines which are avoided by the trustee to trustee exchange. For example the IRS limits the number of rollovers to one a year.

You can have multiple accounts of the same type. The annual contribution limits can be split across accounts. Rollovers and transfers are not part of annual contribution limits.

Comment: If I don't need to transfer any money, could I just set up a second Roth IRA account with the alternative company using my 2015 contribution of $5500? or would that be illegal? Am I correct in assuming the trustee to trustee exchange is for when you are actually exchanging money between the accounts?

Comment: @MHH you are correct.   You could open up a Roth IRA with a second company and make your contribution there.   Note that the $5500 limit is across all of your IRAs and not per account.

Answer (score 2):

Your brokerage might be cautious about allowing you to loan your IRA money
in a Peer-to-Peer lending deal because it might result in a *prohibited
transaction* (e.g. the other Peer is your son-in-law; for the purposes
of IRAs, the spouse of a lineal descendant is treated the same as you, and
the transaction will be treated as if *you* have borrowed money from your IRA).
If you want to
put the money into a lending *club*, then there might be issues of how the
club is structured, e.g. who makes the decisions as to whom the money
is loaned to. Such issues don't arise if you are putting the money into a
money-market mutual fund, for example, but with new-fangled institutions
such as lending clubs, your brokerage might just being cautious.

If you want to open an IRA account directly with a lending club, check if
*the club* offers IRA accounts at all. For this, they will likely need to
have a custodian company that will handle all the IRA paperwork. For
example, the custodian of IRA accounts in Vanguard mutual funds is not
the fund or even Vanguard itself but a separate company named Vanguard
Fiduciary Trust Company. I am sure other large firms have similar set-ups.
Whether your pet Peer-to-Peer lending club has something similar set up
already is something you should look into.

---

This part of the answer applies to an earlier version of
the question in which the OP said that he wanted to invest
in *precious metals.*

Be careful in *what* you invest in when you say you want to invest in **precious metals;** in refusing to buy precious metals for you in your IRA, your
brokerage (as your fiduciary) might be refusing to engage in 
a *prohibited transaction* on your behalf.

Investments in what are called *collectibles* are deemed to have been
*distributed* to you by the IRA, and if this is an early distribution,
then penalties also apply in addition to the income tax. 
*Publication 590* says

> **Collectibles.** These include:
>
> - Artworks,
> - Rugs,
> - Antiques,
> - **Metals,**
> - Gems,
> - Stamps,
> - Coins,
> - Alcoholic beverages, 
>     and
> - Certain other tangible personal property.
>
> **Exception.** Your IRA can invest in one, one-half, one-quarter, or one-tenth ounce U.S. gold coins, or one-ounce silver coins minted by the Treasury Department. It can also invest in certain platinum coins and certain gold, silver, palladium, and platinum bullion.

So, make sure that your new IRA custodian *does* allow you to buy
(say) titanium or Krugerrands in your IRA if that is your pleasure.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, I edited the question accordingly.